# Swift: Timeout when unit testing orientation changes after upgrading to Xcode 10

Tags: swift, unit-testing, timeout, orientation, xcode10

We recently upgraded from Xcode 8 to 10. After -finally- getting everything to compile again, I'm having an issue in our unit tests that involve orientation changes.
What I had been doing to simulate device orientation changes was

```
    XCUIDevice.shared().orientation = .landscapeLeft
    ...
    XCUIDevice.shared().orientation = .faceUp
    ...
    etc.
```

Now when this line is executed, the "device" (simulator of iPhone 8+) is making the appropriate orientation change, but the call ultimately fails due to a timeout on the confirmation:

```
    [iMomTests.DataScreenTests testLandscape] : Failed to set orientation: Error Domain=XCTDaemonErrorDomain Code=15 "Timed out waiting for confirmation of orientation change." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Timed out waiting for confirmation of orientation change.}
```

Comment: I'm seeing this as well, and it's keeping us from moving to Xcode 10 as it's breaking our unit tests. Can this be caught and handled? It doesn't look like it.

Comment: Also, after the first failure, subsequent changes to landscape succeed without an error.

Answer (score 1):

This is an extension I came up with based on KIF's rotation method mentioned above.

```swift
public extension XCTestCase {
    public func waitUntilRotation(to orientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {
        guard UIApplication.shared.statusBarOrientation != orientation else {
            return
        }
        UIDevice.current.setValue(orientation.deviceOrientation.rawValue, forKey:"orientation")
    }
}
```

Then, in the test case you call this method at the start to make sure the orientation is what you are expecting.

```swift
public func testSomethingInPortrait() {
    waitUntilRotation(.portrait)
    ...
}
```

Comment: Could you provide an implementation and more context please ?

Answer (score 0):

We ended up extending KIFSystemTestActor and defining a rotate function:

```
func rotate(to orientation: UIDeviceOrientation) {
    self.simulateDeviceRotation(to: orientation)
}
```